# Parametrization of the rational $x$ where both $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ and $\sqrt{9+x^2}$ are rational

Tags: algebraic-geometry, parametrization

I could parametrize the rational $x$ where $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ is rational as:
$y^2-x^2=1,\ y=\frac{a^2+b^2}{a^2-b^2},\ x=\frac{2ab}{a^2-b^2}$.
$\sqrt{9+x^2}$ is similar. However, I cannot find $x$ where "both" are rational. Is there any method except brute force? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are my thoughts. This not a complete answer, in the end one has to find rational points on a cubic curve (elliptic curve), which I don't know much about.

Setting $t = x-y$, you obtain a rational parametrization of $y^2 - x^2 = 1$ as
$$x(t) = \frac{t^2-1}{2t}, \quad y(t) = -\frac{t^2+1}{2t}, \quad t \neq 0.$$
Similarly for $s = x-y$ you obtain a parametrization of $y^2 - x^2 = 9$ as
$$x(s) = \frac{s^2-9}{2s}, \quad y(s) = - \frac{s^2+9}{2s}, \quad s \neq 0.$$
If you now set $x(t) = x(s)$, you obtain the cubic equation
$$\tag{*}\label{eq}st^2 - s = s^2 t - 9t.$$
So any rational point $(s,t) \in \mathbb Q^2$ which satisfies \eqref{eq} gives you a solution. There is an obvious solution $(s,t) = (0,0)$, but we cannot plug this into $x(s)$ or $x(t)$.

Comment: Solving for $t$ gives $t=\frac{s^2-9 \pm \sqrt{s^4-14s^2+81}}{2s}$, so I guess we just need to find the rational $s$ where $s^4-14s^2+81$ is a (rational) square. This should be doable with the same techniques as the first parts of the answer, right?

Comment: @Milten: $u^2=s^4-14s^2+81$ seems to be isomorphic to Cremona label [48a3](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/48a3/) of rank $0.$ A quick search gives $(s,u)={(0, -9), (3, -6), (-3, -6), (3, 6), (-3, 6), (0, 9)},$ which then are all solutions, resulting in the only solutions to the original problem being the uninteresting ones $t=\pm1$ $x(t)=x(s)=0$ for which $\sqrt{1+0^2}=1$ and $\sqrt{9+0^2}=3.$